# reduce method doesn't work with another dictionary's value

Tags: python

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np

genres = ['classic', 'pop', 'classic', 'classic', 'pop']
plays = [500, 600, 150, 800, 2500]  

genre_id = {}
genres = np.array(genres)
for genre in list(set(genres)):
    genre_id[genre] = sorted(list(np.where(genres == genre)[0]),
                            key=lambda x:plays[x],
                            reverse=True)
```

```py
reduce(lambda x,y : plays[x]+plays[y], genre_id['classic'])
```

and then,

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-324-9751de58a6aa> in <module>
----> 1 reduce(lambda x,y : plays[x]+plays[y], genre_id['classic'])

<ipython-input-324-9751de58a6aa> in <lambda>(x, y)
----> 1 reduce(lambda x,y : plays[x]+plays[y], genre_id['classic'])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I can solve this problem using `collections.Counter`,
but I want to know why it doesn't work in using `functools.reduce`

Comment: I see no use of Counter. Also I see no way reduce can replace this, your code is OK

Comment: How are you using `reduce`? It *returns* a value; it doensn't modify the value you are reducing.

Comment: `x` and `y` aren't necessarily indices you can use to index `play`; one of them is a value from `genre_id['classic']`, the other is a running sum.

Comment: Why are you taking a list, turning it into an array, then a set, and back to a list for iteration?

Comment: I don't see any dictionaries.  I'm unclear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks for your time and interest.  
I accept the answer below what i exactly want.  
If interested, see below answer  
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the `plays` list using `x`, which is the accumulated value.

After the first iteration of your `reduce`, this value is `1300`. That's why the list index is out of range on the second iteration.

Use code like this to see your problem:

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np

genre_id = {}
genres = ['classic', 'pop', 'classic', 'classic', 'pop']
plays = [500, 600, 150, 800, 2500]

genres = np.array(genres)
for genre in list(set(genres)):
    genre_id[genre] = sorted(list(np.where(genres == genre)[0]), key=lambda x:plays[x], reverse=True)

def reduce_function(x, y):
    print(x)
    print(y)
    return plays[x]+plays[y]

print(genre_id)
print(genre_id['classic'])
print(plays)
result = reduce(lambda x,y : reduce_function(x, y), genre_id['classic'])
print(result)
```

I am 99% sure that this is what you want to actually do:

```
 reduce(lambda x,y : x + plays[y], genre_id['classic'], 0)
```

Notice how I provide an initial value of `0` for the accumulator and I never try to access `plays` using the accumulator `x`.

Comment: OMG ... you guess exactly what i wanted.
Thanks for your amazing code